# Push to Bitbucket repo without app password

Tags: git, authentication, bitbucket, ssh-keys

There must be a way to populate and work with a Bitbucket repo without requiring an app password. So how do I do it?

Last night I logged into Bitbucket, created a new repo and pushed to it.
When I populated the repo I was not asked for an app password. I figured that an ssh key exchange assured Bitbucket of my identity and privileges.

This morning I created a new repo on Bitbucket and attempted to push to it from local. This time, at the command prompt when doing the initial push, I was prompted for a username and password. At this point in time, username/password resolution will always fail. Bitbucket requests these credentials and always fails to validated them, having deprecated this authentication method in favour of app passwords.

I'm able to work with the repo I created last night without having to use an app password. But for some reason the repo I created this morning appears to require one.

If I was able to create and work with a repo without requiring app passwords - how can I prevent having to work with them for every project?

Comment: Create ssh key but do not create passphrase on step 3 https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/.

Comment: @kosist "*…do not create passphrase…*" Or use `ssh-agent` or `gpg-agent` with `ssh-agent` mode; `gpg-agent` allows to store SSH keys indefinitely between reboots but configure how often to re-ask for passphrase (I configured to ask once a day).

Answer (score 0):

Firstr, make sure the URL used is an actual SSH one:

```
git@bitbucket.org:me/myRepo
```

Second, an SSH URL would not ask for username/password: the remote hosting repository service would only access key authentication.
It might ask for a passphrase, if you have created the private SSH encrypted.

So double-check the URL in the first and second repo (`git remote -v`).